# How much of the x86 instruction set does blender use?

Tags: algorithm-analysis, parallel-computing, graphics, mathematical-programming, software-engineering

I'm trying to better understand benchmarks that are commonly used for computer hardware.  I've been unable to find an answer to this question.  Extra credit if you can provide a breakdown in percentage per instruction of a blender benchmark.

Comment: This seems off-topic here, since it's a particular piece of software and a particular piece of hardware.

Comment: If you have a suggestion for a better place to ask this question, I'll be sure to post it there.

Comment: You can perhaps try stackoverflow.

Comment: Giving it a shot.  Thanks.  I'll update this with a link if something comes back.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54133600/how-much-of-the-x86-instruction-set-does-blender-exercise